# Make a list of every linux programs which use a certain function

Tags: linux, apt

I'd want to ask you something, that maybe is unfeasible. 
I would need to make a list of programs that use a certain c system function (e.g., mkdir()).
Is there any smart way to do that in Linux Ubuntu? I don't know, maybe combining apt-get source with grep, or something like that.
Such a list has not to be filled with any existent program that uses that function, I'd just need some of them (e.g., the ones that I have installed on my pc).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Function names don't change after compilation, so you may simply look for it in the compiled application file.

Comment: Ok, so you mean to disassemble the binary files and make a grep?

Comment: Yea, make a grep on binary file without dissambling. It will be there.

Comment: OK that works, this it is the answer :) How can I set your comment as answer?

Comment: There you go, an answer :) glad I helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function names don't change after compilation, so you may simply look for it in the compiled application file. Make a grep on binary file without dissambling. It will be there.